# hapi-auth-cookie failing to load session strategy

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

There's not many examples out there for hapi and its auth-cookie plugin but here's what I have so far in an attempt to secure a route. Note, most of the examples I've seen are using an older version of hapi which doesn't seem to quite apply to this situation and im hoping im just missing something simple:

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var Mongoose = require('mongoose');

Mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/rfmproducetogo');

var server = new Hapi.Server(8080, "localhost");

server.pack.register([{
    plugin: require("lout")
}, {
    plugin: require('hapi-auth-cookie')
}, {
    plugin: require("./plugins/togo")
}, {
    plugin: require("./plugins/auth")
}], function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    server.auth.strategy('session', 'cookie', {
        password: 'shhasecret',
        cookie: 'wtfisthisfor',
        isSecure: false,
        redirectTo: false
    });
    server.start(function() {
        console.log("hapi server started @ " + server.info.uri);
    });
});
```

And in my togo plugin I have this route setup to use the session

```
exports.create = function(plugin) {
    plugin.route({
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/togo/add',
        handler: function(request, reply) {
            produce = new Produce();
            produce.label = request.payload.label;
            produce.price = request.payload.price;
            produce.uom = request.payload.uom;
            produce.category = request.payload.category;

            produce.save(function(err) {
                if (!err) {
                    reply(produce).created('/togo/' + produce._id);
                } else {
                    reply(err);
                }

            });
        },
        config: {
            auth: 'session'
        }
    });
};
```

The error im seeing is this:

```
/home/adam/Projects/bushhog/node_modules/hapi/node_modules/hoek/lib/index.js:421
    throw new Error(msgs.join(' ') || 'Unknown error');
          ^
Error: Unknown authentication strategy: session in path: /togo/add
    at Object.exports.assert (/home/adam/Projects/bushhog/node_modules/hapi/node_modules/hoek/lib/index.js:421:11)
    at /home/adam/Projects/bushhog/node_modules/hapi/lib/auth.js:123:14
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at internals.Auth._setupRoute (/home/adam/Projects/bushhog/node_modules/hapi/lib/auth.js:121:24)
    at new module.exports.internals.Route (/home/adam/Projects/bushhog/node_modules/hapi/lib/route.js:118:43)
    at /home/adam/Projects/bushhog/node_modules/hapi/lib/router.js:110:25
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at /home/adam/Projects/bushhog/node_modules/hapi/lib/router.js:107:17
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at internals.Router.add (/home/adam/Projects/bushhog/node_modules/hapi/lib/router.js:104:13)
```

Running node 0.10.28, hapijs 6.x, hapi-auth-cookie 1.02

Comment: Are you still currently experiencing a problem?  I found your repo in GitHub and it seems to work fine.

Comment: hi @dylants I was able to get around the issue by registering the auth strategy within the plugin itself and it works but im not sure this is the best way. I'll always have to make sure the auth plugin is loaded first

Answer (score 1):

this issue occurs when you try to use an authentication strategy before it's actually available.

You're already following a good application setup by splitting the functionality into individual, small plugins with a given scope.

---

**UPDATE:** here's a dedicated tutorial for that problem, [how to fix „unknown authentication strategy“](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/hapi-how-to-fix-unknown-authentication-strategy)

---

A good way to set up authentication and your plugins that rely on authentication is to create an extra "auth plugin" that adds your desired strategies and can be used as a dependency in your other plugins.

[hapi auth plugin example](https://github.com/fs-opensource/hapi-rethinkdb-dash/blob/master/server/authentication/index.js)

```
exports.register = function (server, options, next) {

  // declare/register dependencies
  server.register(require('hapi-auth-cookie'), err => {

    /**
     * Register authentication strategies to hapi server
     *
     * We’re using hapi-auth-cookie plugin to store user information on
     * client side to remember user data on every website visit
     *
     * For sure, we could and will add more authentication strategies.
     * What’s next: JWT (we highly welcome pull requests to add JWT functionality!)
     */
    server.auth.strategy('session', 'cookie', {
      password: 'ThisIsASecretPasswordThisIsASecretPassword',
      cookie: 'hapi-rethink-dash',
      redirectTo: '/login',
      isSecure: false
    });

    server.log('info', 'Plugin registered: cookie authentication with strategy »session«')

    next()

  })

}

exports.register.attributes = {
  name: 'authentication',
  version: '1.0.0'
}
```

In your `/plugins/togo` you set the `authentication plugin` as a dependency (with `server.dependency([array-of-deps])`) which means hapi registers the auth plugin first and the depending ones afterwards.

You register your plugins like this:

```
server.register([{
    plugin: require('./plugins/authentication')
}, {
    plugin: require("./plugins/togo")
}], function(err) { 
  // handle callback
})
```

Check [hapi-rethinkdb-dash](https://github.com/fs-opensource/hapi-rethinkdb-dash) for a detailed example.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

keep in mind if you use server.dependency inside a plugin like Marcus Poehls did, you also need to register that dependency

```
server.register([{
    plugin: require('hapi-auth-cookie')
},{
    plugin: require('./plugins/authentication')
}, {
    plugin: require("./plugins/togo")
}], function(err) { 
  // handle callback
})
```